# Cambiar valor según valor adyacente SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, mariadb

tengo la siguiente tabla y debo cambiar los valores de  la columna "value" (Cambiar  los guiones abajo por espacios en blanco), pero solo de las filas que tengan el valor title en la columna "field"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy dando vueltas con este problema y no se bien por donde tomarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es con REPLACE, el código siguiente evalúa si el field es title y de ser correcto reemplaza '_' por ''

```
declare @tabla as table(
    id int,
    url varchar(10),
    field varchar(10),
    value varchar(100)
)

insert into @tabla(id,url,field,value)values(5,'/img-12','title','imagen_12')
insert into @tabla(id,url,field,value)values(6,'/img-13','caption','descripcion')
insert into @tabla(id,url,field,value)values(7,'/img-14','title','imagen_12')

select id,url,field, case when field='title' then replace(value,'_', ' ') else value end value from @tabla
```

Comment: Perfecto! Es exactamente lo que buscaba gracias!